# Why the behavior of same logic code is different?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, new-operator

Why below code is throwing stack smashing detected if str1=”Overflow” & str2=”stack” but not if str1=”stack” & str2=”Overflow” ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
void string_Concat (char *ptr1, const char *ptr2)
{
  int length1 = strlen (ptr1);
  int length2 = strlen (ptr2);
  int i, j;

  char *temp = ptr1;
  ptr1 = new char[length1 + length2 + 1];
  ptr1 = temp;

  for (i = length1, j = 0; ptr2[j] != '\0'; i++, j++)
    ptr1[i] = ptr2[j];

  ptr1[i] = '\0';
}

int
main ()
{
  char str1[] = "Overflow";
  char str2[] = "stack";
  string_Concat (str1, str2);
  std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

output :
Overflowstack
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated

Here even if input strings are changed it should not give stack smash issue as we are allocating the sufficient space.

Comment: you allocate some memory store a pointer to it in `ptr1` and then immediately do `ptr1 = temp;`. Now any pointer to that allocated memory is lost. It is unclear how or why you expect this to work, or why you not use `std::string`

Comment: already the signature if off. `void string_Concat (char *ptr1, const char *ptr2)` this function cannot concatenate strings.

Comment: There seems to be a big logic issue with this. You should create a char array the length of both strings and place each string in that array, right now you're not even copying the first string.

Comment: A debugger is the correct tool to solve problems like this.  It is a fundamental part of programming on all levels.  Did your debugger tell you where the problem is?

Comment: Also, why is this a `void` function that concats to string 1 and leaves string 2 be? Odd design choice.

Comment: Do the diagnostics here, https://godbolt.org/z/465r86qo9 , help any? Always good to throw in some sanitizers while debugging to see what they dig up.

Comment: btw for the quesiton you asked: When you code has a bug, then some input can make it crash and some input can make it not crash. That shouldnt be a surprise. In either case the code is not doing the right thing. Its called undefined behavior, anything can happen. Worst case is when it appears to be ok

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour in both cases, since `str1` in `main()` has fixed length, and your code appends characters past that length.   The fact it *appears* to work in one case but not another is happenstance - one feature of undefined behaviour is that it can seem to work in some cases, but not others.   And it is not reliable - in some different circumstances, the cases where it works today may not work tomorrow.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  See `std::strcat()`.  Or prefer to use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all kinds of wrong. You have multiple problems.

First, this code:

```
char str1[] = "...";
```

This allocates just enough space to store the string plus the trailing null byte. If you try appending to it, you're eventually going to run into whatever data follows it. This is BAD. You flat out can't.

Then you do this code:

```
char *temp = ptr1;
ptr1 = new char[length1 + length2 + 1];
ptr1 = temp;
```

What happens here. temp points to the value of ptr1. Then you allocate new space for ptr1 -- okay, that's cool. You then destroy the pointer and set it back to temp -- the original ptr1. This is a memory leak and accomplishes nothing at all.

The right way to do this, of course, is to use C++ strings. But you're just learning, so the second-right way to do this is almost what you have.

Allocate space the way you did (sort of), and copy both strings to it, and then return that value. Like this:

```
char * stringConcat(const char * str1, const char * str2) {
     // get the lengths
     char * newStr = new char[length1 + length2 + 1];
     // append the two input strings to newStr kind of like what you did
     return newStr;
}
```

And in main, you would do keep the returned pointer and print it kind of like you did.